# Use 'sort' with char array (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Is it possible to use `std::sort` defined inside `<algorithm>` for sorting `char` arrays according to their ASCII value?  If yes, please provide an example.

Comment: what you want is basically an "alphabetically sorted array" the ASCII value is use for the "standard" way of ordering chars in C and C++, for example a is < than b because of its own ASCII value.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. That is definitely possible. You could know that just by writing some sample code, such as this:

```
char charArray[] = {'A','Z', 'K', 'L' };

size_t arraySize = sizeof(charArray)/sizeof(*charArray);

std::sort(charArray, charArray+arraySize);

//print charArray : it will print all chars in ascending order.
```

By the way, you should **avoid** using c-style arrays, and should prefer using `std::array` or `std::vector`.

`std::array` is used when you know the size at compile-time itself, while `std::vector` is used when you need dynamic array whose size will be known at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, would it work in the same work for string as well?
And can you also take a look at my other question, here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078889/sigsegv-in-gm-plantsiopc1207-on-spoj

Comment: Instead of `sizeof(charArray)/sizeof(*charArray)` you can just use [`std::size(charArray)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size).

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

```
char array[] = "zabgqkzg";

std::sort(array, array+sizeof(array));
```

See http://ideone.com/0TkfDn for a working demo.

Comment: Can you also take a look at my other problem? Here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078889/sigsegv-in-gm-plantsiopc1207-on-spoj

Comment: Size -1 or You will sort with the null. std::sort(array, array+sizeof(array)-1);

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is, of course, to use `std::begin()` and `std::end()`:

```
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array));
```

If you don't have a C++ 2011 compiler, you can implement corresponding `begin()` and `end()` functions, e.g.:

```
template <typename T, int Size>
T* end(T (&array)[Size]) {
    return array + Size;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So begin and end are defined in C++ 2011 compiler and not before that?

Comment: Yes (although they are part of the library; I thing they are declared in `<iterator>`). However, they are easy to define.

Comment: K. Please take a look to an another question by me,here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078889/sigsegv-in-gm-plantsiopc1207-on-spoj

Answer (score 0):

Answers using `sizeof(charArray)` assume that the array must be completely filled. When ran using partially filled array, they produce garbage results.

In that case use:

```
sort(str, str + strlen(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just use this and answered for me.

```
char name[9] = "zxcda";
int length = 0;
for(int i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++)
    length++;
sort(name , name+length);
cout << name;
```